# How do I update my 4.3.3 iPod?

Tags: ipod

I plugged my iPod 4.3.3 into my computer and went on iTunes and I pressed the update button and then it said that I don't have an internet connection even though I can go on Facebook and everything. I don't know if it's something with my computer or my iPod.

Comment: What's the exact wording of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can get on facebook doesnt mean you have wi-fi. You could be runnung off of 3g. Wi-fi is three bars on top left of the screen next to your moible network company. If it says 3g then you dont have wi-fi.

Comment: I believe the poster is referring to their computer connection. Sounds like you're referring to an iOS device that is not in the question.